# Kafka HANA connector bulk mode doesn't work correctly

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect, hana

I am using this connector

```
https://www.confluent.io/connector/sap-hana-connector/
```

this is my configuration

```
{
    "name": "sap",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "com.sap.kafka.connect.source.hana.HANASourceConnector",
        "tasks.max": "10",
        "topics": "sap_OHEM,sap_OHST",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:sap://10.236.242.1:30015/",
        "connection.user": "user",
        "connection.password": "pass",
        "mode":"bulk",
        "poll.interval.ms":"86400000",
        "sap_OHEM.table.name":                          "\"public\".\"OHEM\"",
        "sap_OHEM.poll.interval.ms":                    "86400000",
        "sap_OHST.table.name":                          "\"public\".\"OHST\"",
        "sap_OHST.poll.interval.ms":                    "86400000",
    }
}
```

OHEM has over 300K rows and OHST has about 500. 
My problem is that the connector copy just 100 rows of each of them and push them to the topic over and over again without duing an incremental step. It doesn't copy all the table but just 100 rows of it and than copy it again and again.
I tried with **batch.max.rows** putting 100K as limit, this solved the problem with small tables but not with big tables because it broke JVM memory

Does anyone face the same problem?

Comment: *because it broke JVM memory* -- Well, increase the heap size, then... Otherwise, `bulk` mode repeatedly scans the whole table, as mentioned in the JDBC Connector configuration docs

Comment: hi @cricket_007 the problem is that it doesn't do it. it just copy 100 rows over and over again

Comment: Right, as I said, that is what bulk mode is *meant to do* - scan the table repeatedly (even just parts of it). Setting the max rows is the right thing to do in order to get more rows, but as part of being a Java process, the JVM size needs increased, and this is not a specific problem to JDBC or Kafka connect

Comment: @cricket_007 You mean that if i put Bulk with max rows 100 and poll time of 24h, the connector will read the first 100 rows (and just the first 100 rows not the entire table) every 24h? what will happen if i put max rows 1M and the table will reach 1M+1?